# Como utilizar facebook graph api para enviar mensagens para o messenger de outro usuário

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

Tenho um aplicativo nativo que contém um chat.
Quando o usuário do meu aplicativo enviar uma mensagem eu quero que essa mensagem seja enviada para um usuário através do Facebook Messenger, sem que meu usuário precise utilizar o Messenger.